# Porting code from c++ to c# - Encrypting with RSA PKCS#1 private key

Tags: c#, c++, encryption-asymmetric

I'm trying to port this piece of code from c++ to c#:

```
...
strPrivateKey = "someBase64EncodedPrivateKey";
long sizeKey = DecodeBase64(strPrivateKey, pKey);
const unsigned char* _pKey = pKey;
d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&pRSA, &_pKey, sizeKey);
...

RSA_private_encrypt(sizeOfMessage, pMessage, pSignature, pRSA, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

...
```

So far here is my code:

```
var strPrivateKey = "someBase64EncodedPrivateKey";
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strPrivateKey);

var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

// How to set the private key to the rsa object?!

byte[] someDataToEncrypt = /* Set the data to encrypt */;
var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(someDataToEncrypt, false);
```

EDIT:
I'm not ever sure if it's the class I should refer to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding:

```
At the begin of the private key: "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"
After each line of my private key : "\r\n"
At the end of my private key: "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

And finally, I used OpenSsl.NET as library. This post originally solved my problem: 
[Decrypting RSA using OpenSSL.NET with Existing Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234155/decrypting-rsa-using-openssl-net-with-existing-key)

Answer (score 0):

RSAParameters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) can be fed to the RSACryptoServiceProvider class using the [ImportParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters.aspx) method. You can encode the key within the RSAParameters structure.