# OpenSSL unable to load Public Key

Tags: openssl, ssh-keys

Trying to encrypt a text message via command line on OSX Yosomite 10.10.2

Created public `.pem` key like this:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -t PKCS8 > id_rsa.pem
```

If I try to encrypt myMessage.txt

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem -pubin -in ~/Desktop/myMessage.txt -out ~/Desktop/encrypted.txt
```

I get `unable to load Public key`

If I then type:

```
openssl asn1parse -in id_rsa.pem
```

Returns: `Error: offset too large`

But I have no idea how to fix it.
What should I change to make it work?

Comment: I hit the same issue. When I generated certs in `KeyChain` on macOS it set `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`. When I tried to load the certs with Nginx, it used OpenSSL, which wanted `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Still don't know what went wrong in my question but found a solution:

1. Generate RSA key:

   ```
   $ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024 
   $ openssl rsa -in key.pem -text -noout
   ```
2. Save public key in pub.pem file:

   ```
   $ openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -out pub.pem 
   $ openssl rsa -in pub.pem -pubin -text -noout
   ```
3. Encrypt some data:

   ```
   $ echo test test test > file.txt 
   $ openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey pub.pem -pubin -in file.txt -out file.bin
   ```
4. Decrypt encrypted data:

   ```
   $ openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey key.pem -in file.bin
   ```

It works like a charm

Comment: What if I don't want to regen a key using open ssl?

Comment: Is there a new URL for the link attached at the end of this answer? The current URL has suffered from URL rot.

Comment: Thanks for the question @robotsfoundme . Unfortunately the link is broken by now. There was not more information when following the link. I have removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem also and think a good hint is here:

[How can I transform between the two styles of public key format, one "BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY", the other is "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039401/how-can-i-transform-between-the-two-styles-of-public-key-format-one-begin-rsa)

It seems that the OpenSSL encryption command wants a SSL public key instead of a RSA public key.

We now know enough to tweak the example to make it work.
A SSL public key can be generated from a RSA public key with

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa.pem -RSAPublicKey_in -pubout > id_pub.pem
```

It is then possible to do the encryption step with

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey id_pub.pem -pubin -in ~/Desktop/myMessage.txt -out ~/Desktop/encrypted.txt
```

The default OpenSSL command in MacOSX Yosemite as of this writing appears to be 0.9.8zg. The **rsa** command in this version does not support the capability to run the first command above. I worked around this by installing OpenSSL 1.0.1p.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem when I was extracting public key from certificate.

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.crt > pubKey.pem
```

Afterwards, I wanted to print information about key with command below.

```
openssl rsa -text -pubin -in pubKey.pem
```

And gets an error: `unable to load Public Key`

**Solution**

I opened pubKey.pem in notepad++ and in the *Encoding* menu was UCS-2 LE BOM selected. So I changed it to UTF-8 encoding. Size of pubKey.pem was half of the original one after changing encoding. Then it works like charm.

Tested in Windows and powershell

Answer (score 2):

Your initial solution should work you just have a small typo: To specify key format (PKCS8), the "-m" option is used and not "-t" option (it stand for type of key: dsa, ecdsa, ed25519 or rsa). See [**ssh-keygen**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) man page.

> ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -m PKCS8 > id_rsa.pem

Then, you could encrypt using this:

> openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem -pubin -in ~/Desktop/myMessage.txt -out ~/Desktop/encrypted.txt

And, you could decrypt using:

> openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa -in ~/Desktop/encrypted.txt -out ~/Desktop/decrypted.txt

You could check diffrence between original and decrypted files using text editor or this **[diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)** command:

> diff ~/Desktop/myMessage.txt ~/Desktop/decrypted.txt

In fact, **openssl rsautl -encrypt** command expect a public key with "PEM PKCS8 public key" encoding format but **ssh-keygen** generate a private key in this format and public key in other format adapted to *[authorized_keys](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/)* file in `~/.ssh` directory (you could open keys with text editor to see difference between formats).

Answer (score 0):

I had to struggle with this subject on OSX (Ventura)

- permissions (bad permissions, Could not read... )
- wrong format (PEM/PKCS8 vs "SSH-type")

i came with this solution

```sh
# generate a PRIVATE KEY
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -aes-256-cbc -outform PEM -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
# create a passphrase made of 4 chars minimum

# SUDO ! change permissions to 600 at most
sudo chmod 600 private_key.pem
# but 400 should work and is event more secure
sudo chmod 400 private_key.pem

# SUDO again
# extract THE PUBLIC KEY in PKCS8 file format
sudo ssh-keygen -e -f private_key.pem -m PKCS8 > public_key.pem
# enter your passphrase
```

give the **public** key to someone who wants to protect the data.in.txt file. She or he will do the following to encrypt it:

```sh
# SUDO again
sudo openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pem -in data.in.txt -out data.enc.txt
```

You receive the encrypted file (data.enc.txt) to be decrypted:

```sh
# SUDO again
sudo openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey private_key.pem -in data.enc.txt -out data.out.txt

# then you can read the confidential information
cat data.out.txt
```

you can do the same method so he/she extract his/her public key in order to encrypt your public key to protect it before sending it.