# How to generate RSA keypair with LockBox

Tags: delphi, lockbox-3

I would like to generate RSA keyPair using delphi and LockBox3 library , actually I know how to do it using either a TSignatory or TCodec , but the pairing device that I comunicate with accept only X509 Spec where the generated key by lockbox is assumed as an Invalid key Format , so how can I do it with lockBox are there is another way to achieve that !!
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TP-Lockbox3 TSignatory component uses the OpenSSL library to generate keys (Lockbox also has a native RSA component that doesnt rely on OpenSSL, but that is a different story). The OpenSSL library is named `libeay32.dll` or `libeay64.dll` according to platform.

TSignatory calls the Open SSL function [RSA_generate_key_ex()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html) to generate a PKCS#1 Key in PEM format. This is also referred to as "SSLeay format" or "traditional format". Also [refer](https://openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/rsa.html).

The contents of this key will end in either:

```
'-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

or...

```
'-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

X509 is a broad umbrella. So the question arises, **What encoding formats does your device accept**?

If you need the more modern PKCS#8, then you could try [conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039401/how-can-i-transform-between-the-two-styles-of-public-key-format-one-begin-rsa).