# SecKeyCreateFromData fails on 10.9 with -2147415792

Tags: c++, macos, osx-mavericks, asn.1, seckeyref

I have a code that constructs an RSA public key on MacOS with the help of the security framework. This works fine on 10.11/10.12/10.13, but today I found that this fails on 10.9. Below is the constructor of the class that wraps the key:

```
CRSAPublicKey(const unsigned char* pExponent, const std::size_t nExponentSize, const unsigned char* pModulus, const std::size_t nModulusSize)
{
    static const SecAsn1Template kRsaPublicKeyTemplate[] = {
        { SEC_ASN1_SEQUENCE, 0, NULL, sizeof(ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY) },
        { SEC_ASN1_INTEGER, offsetof(ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY, m_Modulus), 0, 0 },
        { SEC_ASN1_INTEGER, offsetof(ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY, m_Exponent), 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    };
    ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY Asn1Key;
    Asn1Key.m_Modulus.Data = const_cast<unsigned char*>(pModulus);
    Asn1Key.m_Modulus.Length = nModulusSize;
    Asn1Key.m_Exponent.Data = const_cast<unsigned char*>(pExponent);
    Asn1Key.m_Exponent.Length = nExponentSize;
    MacOS::CAsn1CoderReference pAsn1Coder;
    OSStatus nStatus = SecAsn1CoderCreate(&pAsn1Coder);
    // Check nStatus
    SecAsn1Item DerKey;
    nStatus = SecAsn1EncodeItem(pAsn1Coder, &Asn1Key, kRsaPublicKeyTemplate, &DerKey);
    // Check nStatus
    const void* pKeys[] = { kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeyClass };
    const void* pValues[] = { kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeyClassPublic };
    MacOS::CReference<CFDictionaryRef> pParameters(CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, pKeys, pValues, 2, nullptr, nullptr));
    // Check pParameters
    MacOS::CReference<CFDataRef> pKeyData(CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, DerKey.Data, static_cast<CFIndex>(DerKey.Length)));
    // Check pKeyData
    MacOS::CReference<CFErrorRef> pError;
    m_PublicKey = SecKeyCreateFromData(pParameters, pKeyData, &pError);
    // Check m_PublicKey - this fails with "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -2147415792.)"
}
```

I removed some check macros etc, but this should illustrate the call sequence. On 10.9 I get a null pointer from `SecKeyCreateFromData` with an error code  -2147415792. I tried adding the `kSecAttrKeySizeInBits` but that did not help. Meanwhile `SecKeyGeneratePair` with the same `pParameters` works fine, so I assume the issue is with the actual data. Is the ASN.1 coding supported only from 10.10 or something like that?

**UPDATE**

I got messed up in my tests, this actually does not work on 10.11 as well, which seems to corelate with addition `SecKeyCreateWithData`.

**UPDATE 2**

Looking at [cssmerr.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_cssm/libsecurity_cssm-31536/lib/cssmerr.h) this error code seems to be `CSSMERR_CSP_INVALID_KEY`.

Comment: Instead of `CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, DerKey.Data, static_cast<CFIndex>(DerKey.Length))` try using `NULL, DerKey.Data, static_cast<CFIndex>(DerKey.Length)`.

Comment: Both should use the default allocator. Whats the difference?

Comment: See the notes for the function "A new CFData object, or NULL if there was a problem creating the object. Ownership follows the The Create Rule.". It looks like you never release it, which you should do along the way. Also try referencing `SecKeyCreateFromData` like:  `pParameters, *pKeyData, &pError`...

Comment: The CReference is a RAII class that releases the owned object in dtor.

Comment: My only other suggestion at the moment would be to try the [template in a slightly different format](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/df290d594b5fe70fbeb90c061abcb373), and include more thorough exception handling (see [this example](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/pvpkcs11/blob/b36a2db1768c864a06bfbd25bc190557e517027f/src/osx/rsa.cpp#L390-L434)).

Comment: As I said, I have the error checking in place, I just removed those pieces, but thanks for the link, Ill check out how the template format differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not find the answer anywhere I had to solve this myself so I hope this helps others.

I did not find a direct explanation for the behavior changes of `SecKeyCreateFromData`, but since the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1393853-seckeycreatefromdata?language=objc) states:

> Constructs a SecKeyRef object for a symmetric key.

10.12 added a [SecKeyCreateWithData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643701-seckeycreatewithdata?language=objc) which does not mention anything about symmetric keys, maybe they added some additional functionality into `SecKeyCreateFromData` as well and that could be why it was working for me on 10.12 and up.

Nevertheless, to obtain 10.9 compatibility I used [SecItemImport](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395728-secitemimport?language=objc) with the same ASN.1 encoded sequence:

```
static SecKeyRef ImportPkcs1PublicKey(const unsigned char* pExponent, const std::size_t nExponentSize, const unsigned char* pModulus, const std::size_t nModulusSize)
{
    static const SecAsn1Template kRsaPublicKeyTemplate[] = {
        { SEC_ASN1_SEQUENCE, 0, NULL, sizeof(ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY) },
        { SEC_ASN1_INTEGER, offsetof(ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY, m_Modulus), 0, 0 },
        { SEC_ASN1_INTEGER, offsetof(ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY, m_Exponent), 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    };
    ASN1_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY Asn1Key;
    Asn1Key.m_Modulus.Data = const_cast<unsigned char*>(pModulus);
    Asn1Key.m_Modulus.Length = nModulusSize;
    Asn1Key.m_Exponent.Data = const_cast<unsigned char*>(pExponent);
    Asn1Key.m_Exponent.Length = nExponentSize;
    MacOS::CAsn1CoderReference pAsn1Coder;
    OSStatus nStatus = SecAsn1CoderCreate(&pAsn1Coder);
    // Check nStatus and pAsn1Coder
    SecAsn1Item DerKey;
    nStatus = SecAsn1EncodeItem(pAsn1Coder, &Asn1Key, kRsaPublicKeyTemplate, &DerKey);
    // Check nStatus
    MacOS::CReference<CFDataRef> pKeyData(CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, DerKey.Data, static_cast<CFIndex>(DerKey.Length)));
    // Check pKeyData
    SecExternalFormat nFormat = kSecFormatBSAFE;
    SecExternalItemType nType = kSecItemTypePublicKey;
    MacOS::CReference<CFArrayRef> pItems;
    nStatus = SecItemImport(pKeyData, NULL, &nFormat, &nType, 0, NULL, NULL, &pItems);
    // Check nStatus
    SecKeyRef pKey = reinterpret_cast<SecKeyRef>(const_cast<void*>(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(pItems, 0)));
    // Check pKey
    CFRetain(pKey);
    return pKey;
}
```

The trick here was to guess `nFormat` and `nType`, but luckily I found a table with the mapping in Apple open source sources and [CocoaCryptoMac] in Github. I already had the PKCS1 version for my key as seen in the snippet in the question the remaining job was just to set the format accordingly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039401/how-can-i-transform-between-the-two-styles-of-public-key-format-one-begin-rsa/29707204#29707204) answer has a lot of valuable info on PKCS1/PKCS8. Also, initially I was not sure if `pKeyData` is the string or binary form of the key, since there are lots of examples that use the string form with the `SecKeyCreateFromData` function. I just tried out all the options until the binary version worked.