# Check if SSH Private Key is Encrypted

Tags: c, swift, macos, ssh

Key pairs generated with `ssh-keygen` on macOS can have different formats.

- The standard PEM ASN.1 object which is readable by macOS' `SecKey` APIs
- A PEM with textual headers
- OpenSSH Keys
- OpenSSH Encrypted Keys

OpenSSH/BSD uses this non-standardized format [here](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.key?annotate=HEAD).

Now I only need to be able to check if a private key has a passphrase set or not, so I can prompt the user to enter it, without having to deal with the complexities of different key formats.

Is there a quick way on macOS via Swift or C API, to check if a key has a passphrase set?

Comment: Did you check this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926324/seckeycreatefromdata-fails-on-10-9-with-2147415792

Comment: That answer has nothing to do with encrypted private keys.

Comment: Does `libmagic` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented my own OpenSSH check for the 2 most common formats

- For one I'm checking the PEM headers for DEK-Info for Linux-style SSH PEMs
- For OpenSSH style keys I manually parse the format using the class below

```swift
import Foundation

private let opensshMagic = "openssh-key-v1"

public class SSHPrivateKey {

    public struct OpenSSHKey {
        let cipherName: String
        let kdfName: String
        let kdfOptions: Data
        let numKeys: Int

        var isEncrypted: Bool {
            return cipherName != "none"
        }
    }

    public let data: Data

    public init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data
    }

    public func openSSHKey() -> OpenSSHKey? {
        // #define AUTH_MAGIC      "openssh-key-v1"
        //
        // byte[]  AUTH_MAGIC
        // string  ciphername
        // string  kdfname
        // string  kdfoptions
        // int     number of keys N
        // string  publickey1
        // string  publickey2
        // ...
        // string  publickeyN
        // string  encrypted, padded list of private keys

        guard let magic = opensshMagic.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        if data.prefix(magic.count) != magic {
            return nil
        }

        var offset = magic.count + 1

        guard let cipherName = data.consumeString(offset: &offset),
            let kdfName = data.consumeString(offset: &offset) else {
                return nil
        }

        let kdfOptions = data.consumeBytes(offset: &offset)
        let numKeys = data.consumeUInt32(offset: &offset)

        return OpenSSHKey(cipherName: cipherName,
                          kdfName: kdfName,
                          kdfOptions: kdfOptions,
                          numKeys: Int(numKeys))
    }
}

private extension Data {

    func consumeBytes(offset: inout Int) -> Data {
        let n = Int(consumeUInt32(offset: &offset))
        let b = Data(self[offset..<offset + n])
        offset += n
        return b
    }

    func consumeString(offset: inout Int) -> String? {
        return consumeBytes(offset: &offset).utf8String
    }

    func consumeUInt8(offset: inout Int) -> UInt8 {
        let v = self[offset] & 0xFF
        offset += 1

        return v
    }

    func consumeUInt32(offset: inout Int) -> UInt32 {
        var i: UInt32 = 0

        i = (i << 8) | UInt32(consumeUInt8(offset: &offset))
        i = (i << 8) | UInt32(consumeUInt8(offset: &offset))
        i = (i << 8) | UInt32(consumeUInt8(offset: &offset))
        i = (i << 8) | UInt32(consumeUInt8(offset: &offset))

        return i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference between the unencrypted and encrypted private keys is the fact that the key blob is encrypted.  You need to decrypt the private key blob data before you can use the private key blob.  So once the encrypted private key data is decoded, you can treat it the same as the unencrypted private key data.

A unencrypted private key blob PEM file looks like this:

```
—–BEGIN PRIVATE KEY—–
{base64 private key blob)
—–END PRIVATE KEY—–
```

The encrypted RSA private key PEM file looks like this:

```
—–BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY—–
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: {encryption algorithm},{salt}
{base64 encrypted private key blob)
—–END RSA PRIVATE KEY—–
```

e.g.

```
—–BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY—–
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,AB8E2B5B2D989271273F6730B6F9C687
{base64 encrypted private key blob)
—–END RSA PRIVATE KEY—–
```

So to decode the private key data you need to:

1. Parse the [DEK-Info](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.6.1.3) encryption algorithm and the salt (good idea to confirm the first line is: "[Proc-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.6.1.1): 4,ENCRYPTED" as well).
2. Decode the base64 encrypted private key blob.
3. Generate the encryption algorithm "key" and "IV" based on the salt and the passphrase
4. Decode the encrypted private key blob.

Once you have done that the decrypted private key blob can be treated just like the unencoded private key blob.

The number of supported encryption algorithm's are rather large, so you may like to support a sub-set of algorithms. e.g. "DES-EDE3-CBC", "AES-xxx-CBC", etc

To generate the IV you need to convert salt string to binary.  The salt string is a hex encoded string, so convert each two strings characters into a byte using a hex string character to byte converter.

For the generation of the encryption algorithm key you need the key size (e.g. DES-EDE3-CBC is 192bits, AES-256-CBC is 256bits). Build up the key "bits" with a loop appending MD5 hash results to the key until generate all the key bits required.

The MD5 HASH loop generation will consist of:

1. First MD5 Hash: MD5 hash of the first 8 bytes of the IV and the Passphrase
2. All other MD5 Hashes is the MD5 hash of the last MD5 hash result and the first 8 bytes of the IV and the Passphrase

See the openssl source for [EVP_BytesToKey](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/2e9d61ecd81a6a512a0700486ccc1b3784b4c969/crypto/evp/evp_key.c) method for an example of the key bits generation.

The encrypted private key blob can now be decoded using the selected encryption algorithm using the IV and KEY build above.

Comment: Thats not true. The keys are not stored with those "plaintext" PEM headers. They are stored in an ASN.1 object specified in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5208#page-4 . I just wonder why openssl doesn't seem to be able to read it. The PEM has no `DEK-Info` field.

Comment: Ok, apparently it is not ASN1. It looks like my private key PEM has the following format https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.key?annotate=HEAD

Comment: What I described is the openSSL encrypted PEM private key format.  What you pointed to is openSSH private key format, which is not PEM.   Are you sure it's even in a ASN.1 format?  It doesn't say so in the file.

Comment: Looks like openssh public/private keys is a world I didn't know about and they do differ in format from openssl pem files.

Comment: Maybe you should change the title to "SSH-RSA" to be more explicit about what format you are talking about?

Comment: I found this link which looks to break down that non-standard format including links to source code: https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/ and also this link on the difference between the formats: https://coolaj86.com/articles/openssh-vs-openssl-key-formats/

Comment: I guess dealing with different formats is not an option for me. Ill just try to decode and if it fails ill assume it is encrypted. +1 for effort though

Comment: You can tell what file you are dealing with because of the header/footer.  You can test for "BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY" to see if it's in the ssh format.

Comment: Yes, but that doesnt tell me if its encrypted or not. But i can try to decode it as a regular private key, which have a specified asn1 format, and Apples Security framework can read those.

Comment: In the format link above, if you read the bottom of the page it tells you how to determine if it's encrypted or not.

Comment: A SSH key parser in csharp should give you a guide to look at: https://github.com/bhalbright/openssh-key-parser

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I would suggest. Either reading the command line output using readLine() and checking if it asks for a password then do something accordingly.

```
import Foundation

func runCommand(cmd : String, args : String...) -> (output: [String], error: [String], exitCode: Int32) {

    var output : [String] = []
    var error : [String] = []

    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = cmd
    task.arguments = args

    let outpipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = outpipe
    let errpipe = Pipe()
    task.standardError = errpipe

    task.launch()

    let outdata = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String(data: outdata, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
        output = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }

    let errdata = errpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if var string = String(data: errdata, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
        error = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }

    task.waitUntilExit()
    let status = task.terminationStatus

    return (output, error, status)
}

//Sample usage

let (output, error, status) = runCommand(cmd: "/usr/local/bin/node", args: "--version")
print("program exited with status \(status)")
if output.count > 0 {
    print("program output:")
    print(output)
    //HERE YOU CAN CHECK IF PASSWORD REQUEST HAS BEEN MADE
}
if error.count > 0 {
    print("error output:")
    print(error)
}
```

The example code will return your node version installed if there is one, but you could use it to check if a password prompt has been made by the system for the RSA Key.

The other way could be perhaps using a third-party library like [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA) or [BlueRSA](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueRSA) which might help with validation.

Comment: Cannot use this from a sandboxed app

Comment: @ErikAigner I have tried the above code compiled a simple app and in fact, it works as it is based on the standard terminal command line it allows for the execution of shell commands which I assume you have been using in your app. However you have not stated that.

Comment: Also `node` is not a standard system binary

Comment: @ErikAigner It was just an example of a command-line execution and a response read. As I was working on a node project it was the first binary that came to my mind. Give the command a go and try reading a password protected ssh key and you should get the password prompt back as program output: ....... Have a great day.