# How to convert RSA public key to string using BouncyCastle c#

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, key-pair

I'm trying to save RsaKeyParameter Public Key into an SQL database. I get an error that Bouncy Castle can't convert RsaKeyParameters to bytes.

Using BouncyCastle c#.

I've generate an RSA key pair, extracted the private and public keys into variables. I then need to store the public key for verification at a later stage in the application.

I found a post on converting to byte then string as follows;

```
byte[] serializedPublicBytes = 
publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
string serializedPublic = Convert.ToBase64String(serializedPublicBytes);
```

but it doesn't like ToAsn1Object. Just to add this is an example, I'm aware my variable names are different.

```
        RsaKeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        rsaKeyPairGen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = rsaKeyPairGen.GenerateKeyPair();

        RsaKeyParameters PrivateKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Private;
        RsaKeyParameters PublicKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Public;
```

The public key should to byte, then string, to save into the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The public key can be converted to the X.509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo-ASN.1/DER-format using BouncyCastle. This is a binary format from which a string can be generated using Base64-encoding:

```
byte[] publicKeyDer = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKey).GetDerEncoded();
String publicKeyDerBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyDer);
```

Here, `publicKey` is the public key stored in the `RsaKeyParameters`-instance. The reverse process is:

```
byte[] publicKeyDerRestored = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyDerBase64);
RsaKeyParameters publicKeyRestored = (RsaKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKeyDerRestored);
```

Detailed descriptions of the X.509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo- and ASN.1/DER-format can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707204/9014097) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One), respectively.

Both, `publicKeyDer` (as hex-string) and `publicKeyDerBase64`, can be displayed in an ASN.1-Editor, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/

Another approach is to create the PEM-format using the `Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PEMWriter`- and `Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PEMReader`-class
(not to be confused with  `Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PEMWriter`/`PEMReader`):

```
TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject(publicKey);
pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
String publicKeyPEM = textWriter.ToString();
```

and the reverse is:

```
TextReader textReader = new StringReader(publicKeyPEM);
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(textReader);
RsaKeyParameters publicKeyRestored = (RsaKeyParameters)pemReader.ReadObject();
```

The PEM-format is essentially a textual representation of the DER-format using an implicit Base64-encoding (e.g. explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)) and a header (`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`) and footer (`-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`). Therefore, the Base64-encoded part is identical (if line breaks are ignored) for both, `publicKeyDerBase64` and `publicKeyPEM`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I converted to PEM and used the reverse to use in the signature verification process.