# Converting Publickey from PKCS1 to PKCS8 format gives "unable to load Public Key" Error

Tags: ssh, jwt, openssl, cryptography, public-key

I have a public key which has header `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`. I tried to covert this to `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` this type by using below command referred from, [How can I transform between the two styles of public key format, one "BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY", the other is "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039401/how-can-i-transform-between-the-two-styles-of-public-key-format-one-begin-rsa)

`openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in pub.key -pubout`

but it throws,

> **unable to load Public Key**
> 140185314247104:**error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag**:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
> 140185314247104:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
> 140185314247104:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=n, Type=RSAPublicKey
> 140185314247104:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:../crypto/pem/pem_oth.c:33:

but the interesting fact here is, by using the same public key, I am able to verify the signature of a JWT token via jwt.io site.

What is happening here? Can someone help me to understand this scenario?

My public key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: The `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` is not PKCS8 format, it's a SPKI format, sometimes called X509 format.

Comment: Oh okay. thanks for the information. Anyway why is this error happening?

Comment: Can hardly be answered without knowing the key.

Comment: I added my public key above

Comment: This is a public key in X.509/SPKI format with wrong header/footer, i.e. remove `RSA` from header and footer.

Comment: @Topaco How did you find out the header/footer wrong? Can you explain ?

Comment: Load the key in an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/ and compare with the definition of X.509/SPKI s. e.g. *SubjectPublicKeyInfo* in [rfc5280, 4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1).

Comment: Thanks it worked. And is there any way to differentiate a same public key of two different formats?